# While integration of facebook in my applicaion logout will without internet connection Why?

Tags: android

**Why in my application facebook will logout without Internet connection**
i have tried many search on this topic but not get relevant answer 
please help me to get understand this problem

**My Code**
on Log out button click

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: i do not understand...what are you trying to accomplish.????

Comment: my Applicaion will logout without internet connection 
by using LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); on click Button of log out